# Aggregation with .groupby and .transform

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

shg_rg.head()

```
Out[148]: 
                2010        2011        2012  ...     
NUTS_ID                                       ...                               
AT111     270.246017  234.177351  239.672107  ...  
AT112    1119.702129  970.259920  993.026178  ... 
AT113     698.462114  605.241141  619.442569  ...     
AT121     308.610148  267.421174  273.695966  ...  
AT122     265.151045  229.762385  235.153548  ...  

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

I'm trying to add the values per year grouped by the first four characters in the index, NUTS_ID.
I tried with

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.str[:4]).transform("sum")
```

and I get the correct sum:

```
Out[150]: 
                2010         2011         2012  ...         2017         2018  
NUTS_ID                                         ...                                
AT111    2088.410259  1809.678412  1852.140854  ...  1958.588052  1785.564154  
AT112    2088.410259  1809.678412  1852.140854  ...  1958.588052  1785.564154  
AT113    2088.410259  1809.678412  1852.140854  ...  1958.588052  1785.564154 
AT121    1715.282170  1486.350251  1521.226095  ...  1608.654788  1466.544393 
AT122    1715.282170  1486.350251  1521.226095  ...  1608.654788  1466.544393 

[5 rows x 10 columns]
```

However, I would like to have the following dataframe:

```
Out[150]: 
                2010         2011         2012  ...         2017         2018  
NUTS_ID                                         ...                                
AT11     2088.410259  1809.678412  1852.140854  ...  1958.588052  1785.564154  
AT12     1715.282170  1486.350251  1521.226095  ...  1608.654788  1466.544393
```

What would I have to modify in order to get the dataframe I want? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation by [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) because [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) repeat aggregate values for same number of rows like original `DataFrame`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df.index.str[:4]).sum()
print (df2)
                2010         2011         2012
NUTS_ID                                       
AT11     2088.410260  1809.678412  1852.140854
AT12      573.761193   497.183559   508.849514
```

Answer (score 1):

Data:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np; from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'NUTS_ID': {0: 'AT111', 1: 'AT112', 2: 'AT113', 3: 'AT121', 4: 'AT122'}, '2010': {0: 270.246017, 1: 1119.702129, 2: 698.4621139999999, 3: 308.610148, 4: 265.151045}, '2011': {0: 234.177351, 1: 970.25992, 2: 605.241141, 3: 267.421174, 4: 229.76238500000002}, '2012': {0: 239.67210699999998, 1: 993.026178, 2: 619.442569, 3: 273.695966, 4: 235.153548}})
df  = df.set_index("NUTS_ID")
```

df:

```
                2010        2011        2012
NUTS_ID                                     
AT111     270.246017  234.177351  239.672107
AT112    1119.702129  970.259920  993.026178
AT113     698.462114  605.241141  619.442569
AT121     308.610148  267.421174  273.695966
AT122     265.151045  229.762385  235.153548
```

```
grouped = df.set_index(df.index.str[:4]).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

grouped:

```
NUTS_ID                                       
AT11     2088.410260  1809.678412  1852.140854
AT12      573.761193   497.183559   508.849514
```

Comment: You can add your original

Comment: `grouped = df.set_index(df.index.str[:4]).groupby(level=0).sum()`

Comment: Hi @jezreal, i dont copied. when i answer stack overflow i first answer that does the job, after posting that answer, i try to optimize it, if so i update my answer (as i did here).

Comment: yes, problem is your optimalized answer was already posted. So the best is delete it. Or use original answer.

Comment: So is necessary test after edit if not already posted. If yes, then unfortunately it is copy

Comment: Can you post there stackoverflow rule that support you opinion?

Comment: It is about few seconds, so https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252451/removing-own-answer-posted-few-seconds-after-someone-elses-and-is-essentially-t

Comment: your answer was posted after 5 minutes, so edited like already posted so I understand the best delete it. Maybe if few seconds difference it should be OK (in my opinion). If you think I am wrong, be free post meta question.

Comment: It is frowned upon though and usually avoided, if your answer is no different from an earlier answer. It gives the impression that you are only in it for the points and not knowledge sharing.

Comment: @sammywemmy - I am now confused, do you think me?

Comment: sorry. I was referring to @Amirsaleem